# UIPopoverController animates when keyboard pops up

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, animation, uipopovercontroller

Heey,

In my iPad application I have a UIPopoverController with a UIViewController containing some textfields.

When the keyboard comes up, the Popover gets animated to fit. Does anybody know how to disable this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: No I didn't. Still bugs me :/

Comment: Hey, after starting from scratch, I was able to fix this. It turns out that I made my own UIViewController class which just added a little functionality, like completion blocks. Well, apparently I had put some code in this class to animate the keyboards. I felt kinda silly when I realized it but I thought I'd ring back that my popups do not animate anymore. The actual popover window will move, but the controls will stay in a fixed position inside them. My problem is that the text fields were double animating. I think we have different problems even though they sound similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can except make the popovers smaller in height...Its done like that so when your keyboard pops up none of the popover gets covered by it (thus it shrinks back), however i have found it to be annoying at times since it messed with table views (not making them able to scroll all the way and having to resize them)

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if it did actually animate to better part of the screen, I think you mean it actually shrinks the popUp which is mostly not good.(which i see during rotation in my case).  You can not keep the popUp from squishing, UNLESS you move a view.  The best way to handle this is to temporarily move your entire main UIView of the whole screen up with the keyBoard by the difference between the size of your pop up,  and how much that pop up would shrink if you did not move it up...   you can't just move it up by the size of your keyboard,  because popUps up high would then also be effected.  This code below is for when the keyboard rotated,  similar code for when it is first introduced.  easy to do, EXCept for when you rotate the screen, then things get tricky...

in otherwords,  sometimes your UIView will not move at all,  sometimes it will move up by a good 170 points.

//-----------------finding the keyboard top (also used on "didRotate")----very handy,
// took me hours to figure out an absolute always work topOfKeyboard, so here you go.-------

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"            keyboardWillShow");
UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
keyboardRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
keyboardRect = [(UIView*)keyWindow convertRect:keyboardRect toView:mainViewController.view];
keyboardIsVisible = TRUE;
topOfKeyboard = keyboardRect.origin.y;
```

the tricky part is finding the PopUp bottom,  because there appears to be code in the popup itself or the convertRect:toView: code that makes the origin flaky , (if you try to "view" origin after a "convertRect:toView:" code), it wants to move and be in different spots during rotation,(or one of it's super views)   so bottom calc comes out different some times,(not predicable) because of async process of the rotation of different elements possibly because the popUp itself has many superviews down in the pop up. (to see problem in action with pop up and, must have keyboard effecting popup, move the whole view up then log the "origin" and "size" of popUp after the "convertRect:toView:" code)... the "origin" i'm talking about is the origin of the frame after it is translated to the main view (or atleast a couple views up) with the "convertRect:toView:" code....

**update:(it appears if you move down about 3 superviews from the popUp,  the flakiness goes away...    (this code below was in a "didRotate" ipad type of code. That is that the popUp has several superviews before you can get to the one that is projected ontop of the proper frame**

UIPopoverController probably should have a property that has the origin that is predicted after a rotation in it, in a type of "will rotate" kind of code, (because of the keyboard problem),   instead of just the "popoverContentSize", (also should include the popoverContentSize that would have been without the keyboard as another variable, ".. anyway This is how I had to do it, see code below.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void) checkRotation
{
NSLog(@"  ");
NSLog(@"checkRotation");
    if (wasOffset)
    {
        wasOffset = false;
        [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];            
        CGRect frame = carousel.frame;
        frame.origin.y += offset;
        carousel.frame = frame;
        [UIImageView commitAnimations];

        [popPickerController presentPopoverFromRect:zoneButton.frame inView:[zoneButton superview] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }

    if (popPickerController.popoverVisible)
    {

        if (keyboardIsVisible)
        {
            wasOffset = false;

            [popPickerController presentPopoverFromRect:zoneButton.frame inView:[zoneButton superview]
                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];

            upView3 = [[[popPickerController.contentViewController.view superview] superview] superview]; //hey it works... :o)

//NSLog(@"  ");
//NSLog(@"upView3.frame.origin.x    = %f",upView3.frame.origin.x);
//NSLog(@"upView3.frame.origin.y    = %f",upView3.frame.origin.y);
//NSLog(@"upView3.frame.size.height    = %f",upView3.frame.size.height);
//NSLog(@"upView3.frame.size.width    = %f",upView3.frame.size.width);
//NSLog(@"  ");
            popUpRect.origin.x = upView3.frame.origin.x;
            popUpRect.origin.y = upView3.frame.origin.y;
            popUpRect.size.height = popUpSize.height;
            popUpRect.size.width = popUpSize.width; //you must save the size because the keyboard destroys it before you can use it.  very tricky....

//NSLog(@"  ");
//NSLog(@"popUpRect.origin.x    = %f",popUpRect.origin.x);
//NSLog(@"popUpRect.origin.y    = %f",popUpRect.origin.y);
//NSLog(@"popUpRect.size.height    = %f",popUpRect.size.height);
//NSLog(@"popUpRect.size.width    = %f",popUpRect.size.width);
//NSLog(@"  ");
//NSLog(@"  ");
//NSLog(@"keyboardIsVisible    = %d", keyboardIsVisible);
//NSLog(@"  ");
//NSLog(@"keyboardRect.origin.x     = %f",keyboardRect.origin.x);
//NSLog(@"keyboardRect.origin.y     = %f",keyboardRect.origin.y);
//NSLog(@"keyboardRect.size.height      = %f",keyboardRect.size.height);
//NSLog(@"keyboardRect.size.width       = %f",keyboardRect.size.width);
//NSLog(@"topOfKeyboard             = %f",topOfKeyboard);

                CGFloat bottomOfPicker = popUpRect.origin.y + popUpRect.size.height - amountShadowCanEncroach;
//NSLog(@"  ");
//NSLog(@"bottomOfPicker   = %f",bottomOfPicker);
//NSLog(@"topOfKeyboard    = %f",topOfKeyboard);
//NSLog(@"  ");

            if (bottomOfPicker > topOfKeyboard)
            {
                wasOffset = true;
                offset = bottomOfPicker - topOfKeyboard;
NSLog(@"offset    = %f",offset);

                [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];            
                CGRect frame = carousel.frame;
                frame.origin.y -= offset;
                carousel.frame = frame;
                [UIImageView commitAnimations];
            }
        }

        [popPickerController presentPopoverFromRect:zoneButton.frame inView:[zoneButton superview] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

> ```
> and moving the main UIView back
> ```

```
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        - (void) searchDidEndEditing
        {
        NSLog(@"searchDidEndEditing");
keyboardIsVisible = false;
           if (wasOffset)
            {
                wasOffset = false;
                [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];            
                CGRect frame = mainView.frame;
                frame.origin.y += offset;
                mainView.frame = frame;
                [UIImageView commitAnimations];

                if (zoneButton.selected)
                    [popPickerController presentPopoverFromRect:zoneButton.frame inView:[zoneButton superview] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
            }
        }
```